# entity framework and mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

am trying to return the pets that are linked to a certain client but the message Sql = The function evaluation requires that all threads are executed. But I'm not able to find out why this happens, if someone can help me

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {

        if (Session["nomeUsuarioLogado"] != null && Session["usuarioLogadoID"] != null)

        {
            int idcliente = new LoginController().Clientes(this);

            var consultar = from Pets in db.pets
                            join c in db.clientes on Pets.id_pets equals c.id_cliente
                            where c.id_cliente == idcliente
                            select Pets;

            return View(consultar);


            //    return View(db.pets.ToList());
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "login");
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This isn't an error but a feature of the debugger.**

Some properties require code to be executed in order for the property to be read, but if this requires cross-thread interaction, then other threads may have to run as well.  The debugger doesn't do this automatically, but certainly can, with your permission.

Just click the little evaluate icon and it will run your code and evaluate the property.

**For more details, read the full article on [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/eliofek/why-do-we-get-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run).**

Comment: Response debug SELECT `Extent1`.`id_pets`, `Extent1`.`id_cliente`, `Extent1`.`nome`, `Extent1`.`Sexo`, `Extent1`.`especie`, `Extent1`.`raca`, `Extent1`.`idade`, `Extent1`.`descricao`, `Extent1`.`imagem` FROM `pets` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `clientes` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`id_pets` = `Extent2`.`id_cliente` WHERE `Extent2`.`id_cliente` = @p__linq__0

Comment: From what I discovered it must be some query error because when the client id and pet id is the same in the pets table it returns the pet linked to the user, however when the pet id is different it doesn't work.

Comment: I found out it was just a mistake of mine to query the tables was comparing the values ​​incorrectly.